# Unable to access lookup/Id fields via SalesForce REST API

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, lookup

I have an application that accesses a few SalesForce objects via the REST API, however, I don't seem to be able to retrieve or set any fields that are lookup fields.  For example, I have a Form__c object that has a Campaign lookup field as well as the standard RecordType field.  If I run the following query via REST:

> SELECT Id, Campaign_*c FROM Form*_c

I receive an error stating that there is no column called Campaign__c.

Likewise if I try creating a new Form__c object and I set the RecordTypeId field to a specific record type ID, that value is never actually saved in SalesForce.

Is this a limitation of the REST API?  Is it unable to work with lookup fields?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What language/platform are you writing this code in?

Answer (score 0):

In this query:

```
SELECT Id, Campaign_c FROM Form_c
```

It looks like Campaign_c (and Form_c) are missing an underscore. Both should end with `__c` (two underscores and a 'c').

Comment: No, that's Markdown for you ;) They're rendered as italics = editor swallowed the underscores. It's ok if you click "edit" on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Check Profile of user that's integrating via REST?

1. I suspect "field level security" is preventing you from seeing these fields.
2. Plus - in order to use lookups to Campaigns your user must have at least Read access to them (check Campaign object for "Read" not checked or Tab visibility set to "hidden").
3. Campaigns are special, I'm not sure if you don't need the "Marketing User" checked as well on your user record.

As for RecordType - weird. If anything I'd expect it to throw an error if your Profile is not set to be able to use given rec. type (even if you're SysAdmin). Are you using any library that might be swallowing errors?

Last but not least - fire a REST describe call (from your application or from [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)) to `/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Form__c/describe`?